# align* inside beamer tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, amsmath, tcolorbox, themes

While I have given up with [beamer tcolorbox inside align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395036/beamer-tcolorbox-inside-align), I have realized my `mwe` theme is not working to box an align equation either:
The `beamerthememwe.sty`:

```
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{3F51B5}
\usecolortheme[named=dcol]{structure}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{%
  left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,
}

\tcbset{%
  outerlayer/.style={%
    enhanced, sharpish corners=all, colbacktitle=dcol, coltitle=white, coltext=dcol, left=1mm,
    right=6mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm, middle=4mm, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
    % fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black}, % top
    % fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black}, % bottomSmall
    % fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black}, % bottomBig
    title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
    segmentation code={\path[draw=BGrey](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
  },
  innerlayer/.style={outerlayer,
    noparskip, breakable, colback=dcol, coltitle=black, coltext=white, 
    fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape}, 
  bottomtitle=1mm}
}

\newtcolorbox{card}[1][]{%
  outerlayer,
  title=#1,
}

\newtcolorbox{hlcard}[1][]{%
  innerlayer,hbox,
  #1
}
```

and a minimal mwe:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{mwe}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
% \usepackage{roboto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Hello}
  \begin{card}
    \begin{hlcard}[ams align*]
        F&=ma\\
        E&=mc^{2}
    \end{hlcard}
  \end{card}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which is giving error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.14 \end{frame}

? X
No pages of output.
```

This error is gone if I don't use my theme and simply do:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{mwe}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
% \usepackage{roboto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Hello}
  % \begin{card}
    % \begin{hlcard}[ams align*]
  \begin{tcolorbox}[ams align*]
    F&=ma\\
    E&=mc^{2}
  \end{tcolorbox}
    % \end{hlcard}
  % \end{card}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So, there must be something I am missing in the `card` and `hlcard` definition, but I am unable to find it over the weekend.

I will be grateful if you show me some light.

**UPDATE** The only clue I have is that `hbox` is the culprit. I am using `hbox` in `hlcard` to make the `tcolorbox` wrap the text/equation only, not the complete `textwidth`.

NB: `hlcard` is working fine to cover a  single inline equation.

Comment: `hbox` will give an error as `align*` needs to be in vertical mode.  Why do you need the `hbox`?

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I am using `hbox` just to make `tcolorbox` to be around the text. Without `hbox`, it is occupying full `textwidth`. So, I will be happy to leave `hbox` for something else, which makes the `tcolorbox` just wide enough to cover the actual text.

Comment: Use e.g. aligned for the math instead of align. `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$`.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is support for the `aligned` environment from `amsmath` which may be used in any math mode, rather than just a display.  Combining `tcolorbox`'s code for the `math` option with an `aligned` the following settings will provide an `ams aligned` option to your boxes:

```
\tcbset{ams aligned upper/.style={before upper=$\displaystyle\aligned,
  after upper=\endaligned$},
ams aligned lower/.style={before lower=$\displaystyle\aligned,
  after lower=\endaligned$},
ams aligned/.style={ams aligned upper,ams aligned lower}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{3F51B5}
\usecolortheme[named=dcol]{structure}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{%
  left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,
}

\tcbset{%
  outerlayer/.style={%
    enhanced, sharpish corners=all, colbacktitle=dcol, coltitle=white, coltext=dcol, left=1mm,
    right=6mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm, middle=4mm, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
    % fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black}, % top
    % fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black}, % bottomSmall
    % fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black}, % bottomBig
    title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
    segmentation code={\path[draw=BGrey](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
  },
  innerlayer/.style={outerlayer,
    noparskip, breakable, colback=dcol, coltitle=black, coltext=white,
    fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape},
  bottomtitle=1mm}
}

\newtcolorbox{card}[1][]{%
  outerlayer,
  title=#1,
}

\newtcolorbox{hlcard}[1][]{%
  innerlayer,hbox,
  #1
}

\tcbset{ams aligned upper/.style={before upper=$\displaystyle\aligned,
  after upper=\endaligned$},
ams aligned lower/.style={before lower=$\displaystyle\aligned,
  after lower=\endaligned$},
ams aligned/.style={ams aligned upper,ams aligned lower}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Hello}
  \begin{card}
    \begin{hlcard}[ams aligned]
        F&=ma\\
        E&=mc^{2}
    \end{hlcard}
  \end{card}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, it's not possible to use `\hbox` (or `\tcbox`) with multiline maths expressions. What you can do is to use an `empheq` environment colored with a `\tcbox` definition. something like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{mwe}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
% \usepackage{roboto}

\renewtcbox{hlcard}{%
    outerlayer,
   colback=dcol, 
   coltitle=black, 
   coltext=white, 
   fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape}, 
    bottomtitle=1mm,
    nobeforeafter,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Hello}
  \begin{empheq}[box=\hlcard]{align*}
    F&=ma\\
    E&=mc^{2}
  \end{empheq}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]